# NodeJS writeStream empty file

Tags: node.js, filesystems, png

I am trying to use nodeJS to save a processed image stored in a base64 string.

```
var buff = new Buffer(base64data,'base64');
console.log(base64data);

var stream = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/thefile.png');
stream.write(buff)
stream.end()
```

However, the resulting file is empty.

When I take the output of `console.log(base64data);` and decode it locally, it produces a valid png binary, so why is the file empty?

The file is a 3600x4800 px png file (i.e. it's huge), could this be a factor?

Also, I tried `writeFile` as well, no luck.

And yes, `fs` is `require('fs')`

Thanks

Comment: the code is valid, and I can get it working locally, try logging `buff` as that is what you are trying to write (not `base64data`)  to the file to see if there is a problem converting it.  Also you may want to try checking your permissions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

your stream.end() too soon as nothing is written. it is async function remember.

```
var buff = new Buffer(base64data,'base64');
console.log(base64data);

var stream = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/thefile.png');
stream.write(buff);
stream.on("end", function() {
  stream.end();
});
```

Comment: I am using mkpdf library, and this didn't work for me at all, as the end event is never reached if end() wasn't called. when using mkpdf i am actually creating the writestream and then pass it to the library and then call pipe() method.

Answer (score 6):

Better:

```
var buff = new Buffer(base64data,'base64');
console.log(base64data);

var stream = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/thefile.png');
stream.write(buff);
stream.end();
stream.on('finish', () => {
     //'All writes are now complete.'
});
stream.on('error', (error) => {...});
```

Comment: Can you provide some details about the lines you added?

Comment: This is not better; it doesn't work. You put `stream.end()` before waiting for an event.