# NodeJS piping from readable to file writeStream not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to pipe content to file. Here's what I've wrote:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;

var ws = fs.createWriteStream('xfiles.txt');
var rs = new Readable;

ws.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Written ' + ws.bytesWritten + ' ' + ws.path);
});

rs.push('foo bar baz');
rs.push('foo bar baz');
rs.push('foo bar baz');
rs.push(null);

rs.pipe(ws);
ws.end();
```

I expected the xfiles.txt to have 3 lines of 'foo bar baz'. But the output tells me that 0 bytes written, and when I check xfiles.txt it's empty.

What do I miss?

**EDIT**

Sorry, found the answer right after posting this question. The answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338350/nodejs-writestream-empty-file) solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer just after posting this question. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338350/nodejs-writestream-empty-file) have the answer that also solved my problem.

What I have to do is to call `ws.end()` after the stream completes its async operation. So I have to put it inside a callback:

```
ws.on('end', function() {
    ws.end();
});
```